# Find the longest string in a nested array using Recursion in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have seen various answers which give a solution to finding the longest string in an array. My problem is, I want to find the longest string in a nested array. The nesting level may be of N-levels or just two levels deep. My initial solution is as follows:

```
    let myArray = [
    'ABC',
    'ABCD',
    'ABCDE',
    [
      'ABC',
      'ABCABABA',
      [
        'ABABABABABABABABAZZ'
      ],
    'ABCABABASS',

     ],
   'ABCDEFGH',
   'ABABABABZZQ'
   ]

function longestString(arr) {
let longestStr = ''
arr.forEach(item => {
if(typeof item === 'string') {
  if(item.length > longestStr.length) {
    longestStr = item;
    console.log('Longest Item', item);
  }    
} else {
    longestString(item)
  }
})
 return longestStr;
}

console.log(longestString(myArray))
```

Observed Output -> ABABABABZZQ

Expected Output -> 'ABABABABABABABABAZZ'

What is the tweak needed to print only the longest string?

Comment: The problem is that you are printing inside `longestString`. Instead, each iteration of the function should just return the longest string found, and when calling recursively, you should compare the returned value to the current stored longest string.

Comment: An equivalent solution to @Matt would be to pass the current longestStr as a parameter to the function so your can always compare the new strings to it. (Posted an answer here if it's not clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the return value of the recursive call - put the returned string through the same test that you put the `item` through, check if it's longer than `longestStr`, and if so, reassign `longestStr`:

```js
let myArray = [
  'ABC',
  'ABCD',
  'ABCDE', [
    'ABC',
    'ABCABABA', [
      'ABABABABABABABABAZZ'
    ],
    'ABCABABASS',

  ],
  'ABCDEFGH',
  'ABABABABZZQ'
]

function longestString(arr) {
  let longestStr = ''
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (typeof item === 'string') {
      if (item.length > longestStr.length) {
        longestStr = item;
      }
    } else {
      const nestedLongest = longestString(item);
      if (nestedLongest.length > longestStr.length) {
        longestStr = nestedLongest;
      }
    }
  })
  return longestStr;
}

console.log(longestString(myArray))
```

Or, to be somewhat more DRY:

```js
const myArray=['ABC','ABCD','ABCDE',['ABC','ABCABABA',['ABABABABABABABABAZZ'],'ABCABABASS',],'ABCDEFGH','ABABABABZZQ']

function longestString(arr) {
  let longestStr = '';
  const check = str => {
    if (str.length > longestStr.length) longestStr = str;
  };
  arr.forEach(item => {
    check(typeof item === 'string' ? item : longestString(item));
  });
  return longestStr;
}

console.log(longestString(myArray))
```

Another option would be to have an inner function that gets called, while assigning to a `longestStr` variable that's persistently in scope until the end of the `longestString` function - meaning that you don't have to worry about the results of the recursive calls:

```js
const myArray=['ABC','ABCD','ABCDE',['ABC','ABCABABA',['ABABABABABABABABAZZ'],'ABCABABASS',],'ABCDEFGH','ABABABABZZQ']

function longestString(input) {
  let longestStr = '';
  const check = str => {
    if (str.length > longestStr.length) longestStr = str;
  };
  function recursiveFn(arr) {
    arr.forEach((item) => {
      if (typeof item === 'string') check(item)
      else recursiveFn(item);
    });
  }
  recursiveFn(input);
  return longestStr;
}

console.log(longestString(myArray))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array, and then use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to find the longest item:

```js
const myArray = [
  'ABC',
  'ABCD',
  'ABCDE', [
    'ABC',
    'ABCABABA', [
      'ABABABABABABABABAZZ'
    ],
    'ABCABABASS',

  ],
  'ABCDEFGH',
  'ABABABABZZQ'
]

const result = myArray
  .flat(Infinity)
  .reduce((r, s) => s.length > r.length ? s : r);
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Problem with this method is that you are iterating the collection twice, it is quite inefficient. Not a real problem on a small data set but increases with the size of the input.

Comment: This is a functional solution that splits the problem into two simple parts. Both parts are O(n), which translate to O(2n). In CS O(2n) is equivalent to O(n). This means that performance optimisation will be required only for huge arrays. In JS huge recursive solutions will fail most of the time (stack overflow).

Comment: You do realise that flat is a recursive function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Comment: And flat copies the array and consumes a huge amount of memory compared to a single reduce that only keeps a single string as an accumulator. The single reduce will only consume memory for the stack to the depth of the array nesting and will fail orders of magnitude later that flat.

Comment: When you say in CS O(2n) is equivalent to O(n), this may be true on the client side running in the browser where taking twice as long doesn't make much difference, but if it is on the server where you are servicing thousands of requesting per second it may be the difference between $500 a month in hosting costs vs $1,000 a month. That is not equivalent in my book.

Comment: Of course it's recursive, and consumes more memory. However, the problem is less memory than the stack overflow (no tail recursion optimisation is JS). So, both solutions will probably fail for huge nesting structures. This means that for huge structures we'll use other solutions. With small and medium structures, both solutions will work. Flattening 1st is just simpler, since we know how to flatten, and we know how to find the longest in an array, we can compose both. O(n)  or o(2n) - this is a linear complexity, and we can drop the fixed number. Your solution is a bit more optimised.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `longestStr` outside the function and also you have to use the `return` keyword

```
return longestString(item)
```

```js
let myArray = [['ABC','ABCD','ABCDE',
    ['ABC','ABCABABA',
    ['ABABABABABABABABAZZ'],
    'ABCABABASS'],
   'ABCDEFGH',
   'ABABABABZZQ']]
   
let longestStr = ''
function longestString(arr) {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if(typeof item === 'string') {
      if(item.length > longestStr.length) {
        longestStr = item;
        console.log('Longest Item', item);
      }    
      } else {
        return longestString(item)
      }
  });
  return longestStr;
}

console.log(longestString(myArray));
```

**EDIT - You can pass `longestStr` as parameter to `longestString` function**

```js
let myArray = [['ABC','ABCD','ABCDE',
    ['ABC','ABCABABA',
    ['ABABABABABABABABAZZ'],
    'ABCABABASS'],
   'ABCDEFGH',
   'ABABABABZZQ']]

function longestString(arr,longestStr) {
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if(typeof item === 'string') {
      if(item.length > longestStr.length) {
        longestStr = item;
        console.log('Longest Item', item);
      }    
      } else {
        var value = longestString(item,longestStr);
        if(value.length > longestStr.length){
           longestStr = value;
        }
        return longestStr;
      }
  });
  return longestStr;
}

console.log(longestString(myArray,''));
```

Comment: You are maintaining the `longestStr` in the global context. We can passed  as an argument to `longestString` itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single reduce

```js
const myArray = [
  'ABC',
  'ABCD',
  'ABCDE', [
    'ABC',
    'ABCABABA', [
      'ABABABABABABABABAZZ'
    ],
    'ABCABABASS',

  ],
  'ABCDEFGH',
  'ABABABABZZQ'
];

const findLongestStr = array => array.reduce((result, item) => typeof item === 'string' ? item.length > result ? item : result : findLongestStr(item), '');
  
console.log(findLongestStr(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursively call the `findLongestStr` if the input is `Array` and maintain the current maximum value.

```
let myArray = [
    'ABC',
    'ABCD',
    'ABCDE',
    [
      'ABC',
      'ABCABABA',
      [
        'ABABABABABABABABAZZ'
      ],
    'ABCABABASS',

     ],
   'ABCDEFGH',
   'ABABABABZZQ'
   ];

function findLongestStr(input){
  return input.reduce(function(o,i){
     if(i.constructor === Array){
        var value = findLongestStr(i);
        console.log("value array => ",value);
        if(o.length < value.length){
          o = value;
        }
     }else{
           console.log("value i => ",i);
        if(o.length < i.length){
          o = i;
        }
     }
     return o;
  },"");
}

console.log("max length => ",findLongestStr(myArray));
```

Working jsFiddle demo - https://jsfiddle.net/k4yo35hb/1/

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with you code is that you redefine `longestStr` each time the recursive function is called. Leaving you no way of comparing the longest string from each recursive call.

Using `reduce()` is a nice way to find the max of a regular un-nested array. You can add a little bit of recursion and still use `reduce()` for this which takes care of maintaining state between recursions because all the recursion unwinds within the `reduce` function:

```js
let myArray = ['ABC','ABCD','ABCDE',['ABC','ABCABABA',['ABABABABABABABABAZZ'],'ABCABABASS',],'ABCDEFGH','ABABABABZZQ']


function longestString(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((longest, item) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      let rec = longestString(item)
      if (rec.length > longest.length) longest = rec
    } else if (item.length > longest.length) longest = item;

    return longest
  }, '')
}

console.log(longestString(myArray))
```

Comment: Without providing the default intial value in `reduce` function it's getting undefined in `longest` at first place.

Comment: If you don't define the initial accumulator in a reduce function it uses the first element of the array, not undefined. In this case you need to define the accumulator as an empty string just incase the first item is an array.

Answer (score 0):

with respect to @Adrian Brand clean answer, here is the solution:

```
const findMaxStringInArray = (array, lastMax = '' ) => array.reduce((curMax,item)=>typeof item === 'string'?  item.length > curMax.length? item : curMax :  findMaxStringInArray(item, curMax) ,lastMax);
```